# Foreign Keys & character limits in Postgres and Clojure JDBC

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, clojure

I'm making myself a facebook/twitter combination thing just for fun, but I am not 100% sure about some semantics with JDBC stuff. I am unsure on how to set a field to be a foreign key or how to limit the amount of characters in a varchar field.

My code (with comments to show where I need help) is as follows

```
(ns twitface.models.migration
  (:require [clojure.java.jdbc :as sql]))

(defn create-tables []
  (sql/with-connection (System/getenv "DATABASE_URL")
    (do 
      (sql/create-table :users
                        [:id :serial "PRIMARY KEY"]
                        [:email :varchar "NOT NULL"]
                        [:password :varchar "NOT_NULL"]
                        [:full-name :varchar "NOT NULL"]
                        [:pref-name :varchar]
                        [:created_at :timestamp "NOT NULL" "DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"])
      (sql/create-table :relations
                        [:id :serial "PRIMARY KEY"]
                        [:relating-user :numeric] ; foreign key
                        [:related-user :numeric]  ; foreign key
                        [:status :varchar])
      (sql/create-table :posts
                        [:id :serial "PRIMARY KEY"]
                        [:user :numeric "NOT NULL"]    ; foreign key
                        [:destination-user :numeric "NOT NULL"] ; foreign key
                        [:message :varchar "NOT NULL"] ; 180 char limit
                        [:created_at :timestamp "NOT NULL" "DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"])
      (sql/create-table :comments
                        [:id :serial "PRIMARY KEY"]
                        [:user :numeric "NOT NULL"]    ; foreign key
                        [:message :varchar "NOT NULL"] ; 180 char limit
                        [:created_at :timestamp "NOT NULL" "DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"]))))
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for foreign key, use `references` as sql:

```
(defn create-tables []
  (sql/with-connection (System/getenv "DATABASE_URL")
    (do
      (sql/create-table :users
                        [:id :serial "PRIMARY KEY"]
                        [:email "varchar(50)" "NOT NULL"]
                        [:password "varchar(30)" "NOT NULL"])
      (sql/create-table :relations
                        [:id :serial "PRIMARY KEY"]
                        [:related_user :serial "references users (id)"]
                        [:status "varchar(10)"]))))
```

Comment: Thanks! One small question: you've used a serial data type for the related_user field. Wouldn't that cause it to just pick it's own number? Or is it because it's referencing another serial field that it's like that?

Comment: yes, please check out postgresql docs: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/tutorial-fk.html

Answer (score 3):

When you don't find documentation, check out the test included in the project and if that doesn't help check out the source code - the best thing about using open source. I tried to look at the test and found that you can use `VARCHAR(180)` instead of using `:varchar` to specify the limit of the column and similarly you can use normal SQL construct to specify foreign key

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't thought of using tests as documentation before. I'll be sure to check them before asking on SO next time